# Cython: error C2106: '=': left operand must be l-value

Tags: python, c, cython

I know problems about this error code were answered several times but I couldn't find any answer that solves this specific problem.

I am building a 3D connected component algorithm by using Cython. When I compile the .pyx file, the compiler gives the following error:

```
connectedComponent3D.c(3026): error C2106: '=': left operand must be l-value
```

At line 3026 of connectedComponent3D.c file I see the following code:

```
            /* "connectedComponent3D.pyx":49
 *                         labels[newItem[0], newItem[1], newItem[2]] = currentComponent
 *                         neighbors = get26Neighbors(newItem[0], newItem[1], newItem[2])
 *                         for neighbor in neighbors:             # <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
 *                             if binary3DArray[neighbor[0], neighbor[1], neighbor[2]] == 1:
 *                                 labels[neighbor[0], neighbor[1], neighbor[2]] = currentComponent
 */
            __pyx_t_31 = (__pyx_v_neighbors + 26);
            for (__pyx_t_32 = __pyx_v_neighbors; __pyx_t_32 < __pyx_t_31; __pyx_t_32++) {
              __pyx_t_30 = __pyx_t_32;
              __pyx_v_neighbor = (__pyx_t_30[0]); //Line 3026
```

Unfortunately, I can't see anything wrong with the source code. Can someone help me about what is wrong?

Here is the connectedComponent3D.pyx in case you need it:

```
from collections import deque
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
cimport cython
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.debug)

def main(binary3DArray):
    cdef q = deque()
    cdef int[:,:,:] binary3DArray_view = binary3DArray
    cdef np.ndarray[np.int_t, ndim=3] labels = connectedComponent3D(binary3DArray_view, q)
    return labels

@cython.wraparound(False)
@cython.nonecheck(False)
@cython.boundscheck(False)
cdef connectedComponent3D(int[:,:,:] binary3DArray, q):

    cdef np.ndarray[np.int_t, ndim=3] labels = np.zeros_like(binary3DArray)

    cdef Py_ssize_t zmax = <Py_ssize_t>binary3DArray.shape[0]
    cdef Py_ssize_t ymax = <Py_ssize_t>binary3DArray.shape[1]
    cdef Py_ssize_t xmax = <Py_ssize_t>binary3DArray.shape[2]
    cdef Py_ssize_t z, y, x
    cdef int currentComponent = 1
    cdef int neighbors[26][3]
    cdef int neighbor[3]
    cdef int newItem[3]

    for z in range(1, zmax-1):
        logging.debug(z)
        for y in range(1, ymax-1):
            for x in range(1, xmax-1):
                if binary3DArray[z, y, x] == 1 and labels[z, y, x] == 0:
                    q.append((z,y,x))

                    while not q.empty():
                        newItem = q.popleft()
                        labels[newItem[0], newItem[1], newItem[2]] = currentComponent
                        neighbors = get26Neighbors(newItem[0], newItem[1], newItem[2])
                        for neighbor in neighbors:
                            if binary3DArray[neighbor[0], neighbor[1], neighbor[2]] == 1:
                                labels[neighbor[0], neighbor[1], neighbor[2]] = currentComponent
                                q.append(neighbor)
                    currentComponent += 1
    return labels

@cython.wraparound(False)
@cython.nonecheck(False)
@cython.boundscheck(False)
cdef get26Neighbors(int z, int y, int x):
    """
    Input arguments: index -> This is the index(z, y, x) of element whose neighbors are need to be
    calculated. type: tuple
    Returns: neighbors -> indices of 26-neighbors 

    This function calculates all 16 neighbors of an element in 3D space. 
    In order to see what a 26-neighbors is check the 29/38 slide in below link. Left figure is 6-n and
    right one is 26-neighbors.
    Link: http://slideplayer.com/slide/8645709/

    """

    cdef int neighbors[26][3]
    neighbors = [[z-1, y-1, x-1],   [z-1, y-1, x],   [z-1, y-1, x+1],
                 [z-1, y, x-1],     [z-1, y, x],     [z-1, y, x+1],
                 [z-1, y+1, x-1],   [z-1, y+1, x],   [z-1, y+1, x+1],
                 [z, y-1, x-1],     [z, y-1, x],     [z, y-1, x+1],
                 [z, y, x-1],       [z, y, x+1],     [z, y+1, x-1],
                 [z, y+1, x],       [z, y+1, x+1],   [z+1, y-1, x-1],
                 [z+1, y-1, x],     [z+1, y-1, x+1], [z+1, y, x-1],
                 [z+1, y, x],       [z+1, y, x+1],   [z+1, y+1, x-1],
                 [z+1, y+1, x],     [z+1, y+1, x+1]]

    return neighbors
```

Comment: Did you perhaps mean `__pyx_v_neighbors` instead of `__pyx_v_neighbor`?

Comment: If you mean `for neighbor in neighbors:` , I don't see anything wrong with that.

Comment: Knowing the type of `__pyx_v_neighbor` might be useful. From python code I would guess that it is some array type. You cannot assign to an array.

Comment: @Gerhardh I guess it is of type `int*`

Comment: You have the code, you don't need to guess. :) I guess it is something like `int __pyx_v_neighbor[3]` because an `int*` would normally be a perfect l-value.

Comment: @Gerhardh Thank you very much. I declared neighbor as `cdef int* neighbor = <int*>malloc(3 * sizeof(int))` . Now it works :)

Comment: No, I think it does probably not work! This line `__pyx_v_neighbor = (__pyx_t_30[0]); //Line 3026` would cause a memory leak as you lose the pointer from `malloc`

Comment: "left operand must be l-value" means the left operand is something you can't assign to, like an array.

Comment: You're allocating `neighbors` on the stack in `get26Neighbors` and then returning it to another function. Unfortunately when `neighbors` makes it back out of `get26Neighbors` it gets deallocated because the original pointer that held the data went out of scope. Rather than using a pointer array I'd suggest using a typed memoryview or numpy array to hold the data. If you really do need to use a pointer array, allocate the memory on the heap or copy/paste the logic in `get26Neighbors` into `connectedComponent3D` so the stack allocation happens in the function that needs the data.

Comment: @ngoldbaum I see your point and thank you for the update. It is weird that when I removed the declaration of neighbor it worked just fine.